# How to Create Deferrable Scope in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to create a deferrable block in kotlin, were i will doing some db operations inside the scope say

```
 val deferredObject = Deferrable {  // This block should not execute until i invoke
  dao.someFunctionA()
  dao.someFunctionB()
}
```

Then i will sending the above deferred object to some other executor to execute, say

```
fun deferrableExecutor(deferredObj : Deferred){
    deferredObj.invoke() // During this invoke i need to execute all the methods inside the deferrable block
}
```

I need a behaviour like this, but i am not sure how to create deferred block in kotlin, can anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you really need coroutines, because your DAO methods must be suspendable to have some advantage from this. 
But If you need this, the [`suspend`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/suspend.html) function creates an suspendable lambda that you may invoke later:

```
val deferredObject = suspend {
    dao.someFunctionA()
    dao.someFunctionB()
}

suspend fun deferrableExecutor(deferredObj : suspend () -> Any){
    deferredObj()
}

deferrableExecutor(deferredObject)
```